# Voltage follower with LF411 shows -6dB instead of 0dB

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, bode-plot, pspice

I designed the circuit shown in the first picture. It is a voltage follower realised with a LF411, connected to its output is a load of 10k and an AC source on its input with an amplitude 0.5V. I am wondering why the simulation (PSpice 9.1) shows me a more or less constant amplification of -6dB until 1MHz, where I would actually expect 0dB. Does anybody know why the amplitude response looks like that (see second picture)?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the input is only 0.5V (-6db). You should divide the output voltage by the input voltage to avoid such problems or even better use 1V when doing an AC analysis.

Comment: Wow that was quick :D Thank you, I oversaw that ..